# pdf content rendered into browser instead of display

Tags: php, symfony1, download

Using symfony1 I prepare a pdf file on the server side and return it to the browser. When running this code with the same browser on multiple servers/sites it is working fine, except one server. In this case the pdf content rendered into the browser window instead of displaying it embedded (or even popping up a download window). This weird behaviour is independent of the browser (tried with the latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari). Please find below the log lines, these are the same on every server.

```
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfView} initialize view for "report/runReport"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfView} render ".../frontend/modules/report/templates/runReportSuccess.php"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfFilter} render to client
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send status "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Pragma": "public"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Cache-Control": "cache-control=max-age=0,must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "binary"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Content-Length": "77225"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename="aging-debt.pdf""
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send header "Charset": "utf-8"
Dec 27 00:03:30 frontend: {sfResponse} send content (77225 o)
```

Comparing the server environment regarding to a working and a non-working server, both runs Debian 6.0 with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Suhosin-Patch.

The url is opened with a simple JavaScript window.open, no other code or event listener running on the client side. Please advise, what setting should I check to resolve this. Google-d it, but found only unanswered questions, like [Browser shows pdf content instead of html page some times? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618605/browser-shows-pdf-content-instead-of-html-page-some-times).

Comment: And have you verified that browser actually receives that headers from symfony log? It looks like bad server/proxy configuration that overwrites or drops some of these headers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check it. The truth is that I connect to both servers mentioned above via an ssh tunnel.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @dev-null-dweller that the server is munging the headers. You might try Fiddler or WireShark if Firebug or Chrome console's don't work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you guys. There was an error in my code, that led to returning another http headers in some cases, but was tricky to find. Also thanks for mentioning Fiddler, did not know it.